# Pandas: forcing merge from multiple rows from Excel file into a single row(s) into single lines

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've been given a few sets of MS-Excel worksheets with a lot of nested data in areas, and I have researching for a few hours looking for a way to reduce each 'id' row to single rows.  Specifically merging 'Step ID', 'Install Steps', and 'Expected step' into single lines with some formatting.

Here is shortened simple of the data within the Excel sheets I need to convert.

| Name | ID | Host | Step ID | Install Step | Expected step | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 4 | Cat | 1 | Move x to y | x is with y | x will protest |
|  |  |  | 2 | move x away from y | x and y are not together | y will protest |
| Test2 | 5 | Dog | 1 | remove x from tank | y is alone |  |
|  |  |  | 2 | Drop duplicate of y, y2 in tank | y1 is not alone | y1 will protest |
|  |  |  | 3 | Drop more duplicates of y into tank, y3 and y4 |  | y1 and y2 will protest |
| test 3 | 6 | Dog | 1 | empty tank | nothing is in tank |  |

And I am looking to transform this excel sheet into the following

| Name | ID | Host | Install Step | Expected step | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 4 | Cat | 1 - Move x to y 2 - move x away from y | 1 - x is with y 2 - x and y are not together | 1 - x will protest 2 - y will protest |
| Test2 | 5 | Dog | 1 - remove x from tank 2 - Drop duplicate of y, y2 in tank 3 - Drop more duplicates of y into tank, y3 and y4 | 1 - y is alone 2 - y1 is not alone | 2 - y1 will protest <br / > y1 and y2 will protest |
| Test3 | 6 | Dog | 1 - empty tank | 1 - nothing is in tank |  |

I have testing a few of the other Stackoverflow questions and repsonses for pandas, but the few that closely match my need just fill in the empty areas with duplicate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [**`melt()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the dataframe:

```py
melt = df.melt(['Name', 'ID', 'Host', 'Step ID']).ffill()

#      Name   ID  Host  Step ID      variable               value
# 0   Test1  4.0   Cat        1  Install Step         Move x to y
# 1   Test1  4.0   Cat        2  Install Step  move x away from y
# ...
# 16  Test2  5.0   Dog        3         Extra     y1 will protest
# 17  Test3  6.0   Dog        1         Extra     y1 will protest
```

You can combine the `Step ID` and `value` columns in one shot:

```py
melt.value = melt['Step ID'].astype(str) + ' - ' + melt.value
melt = melt.drop('Step ID', axis=1)

#      Name   ID  Host      variable                   value
# 0   Test1  4.0   Cat  Install Step         1 - Move x to y
# 1   Test1  4.0   Cat  Install Step  2 - move x away from y
# ...
# 16  Test2  5.0   Dog         Extra     3 - y1 will protest
# 17  Test3  6.0   Dog         Extra     1 - y1 will protest
```

Then join each group's `value` list together with `\n` and [**`unstack()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to pivot back to the wide table:

```py
melt.groupby(['Name', 'ID', 'Host', 'variable']).agg('\n'.join).unstack()
```

|  | Name | ID | Host | Expected Step | Extra | Install Step |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Test1 | 4.0 | Cat | 1 - x is with y\n2 - x and y are not together | 1 - x will protest\n2 - y will protest | 1 - Move x to y\n2 - move x away from y |
| 1 | Test2 | 5.0 | Dog | 1 - y is alone\n2 - y1 is not alone\n3 - y1 an... | 1 - y will protest\n2 - y1 will protest\n3 - y... | 1 - remove x from tank\n2 - Drop duplicate of ... |
| 2 | Test3 | 6.0 | Dog | 1 - nothing is in tank | 1 - y1 will protest | 1 - empty tank |

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Looks like melt will resolve  it nicely.

Comment: Great, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the formatting bit:

```
df = df.ffill()  # forward fill the empty areas
step_id_str = df['Step ID'].astype(str)
for col in ['Install Step','Expected Step','Extra']:
    df[col] = step_id_str + ' - ' + df[col]
```

For merging the rows:

```
group = df.groupby('ID')
for col in ['Install Step','Expected Step','Extra']:
    df[col] = group[col].transform(lambda s: '\n'.join(s))
df = df.drop('Step ID', axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df
```

Comment: I was able to use part of you answer also.  Thank you for the help